# How to get a function to call another function

Tags: solidity

this is a part of my code , so far it retrieves the price of eth at the current time and then the price of eth after 60 seconds .

```
function test() payable{
    Log("Contract created.");
    update();
    update2();
}

 function getInitialPrice() constant returns (uint) {
   return initialPrice;
}

function getFinalPrice() constant returns (uint) {
    return finalPrice;
}

function __callback(bytes32 _myid, string _result) {
    require (msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
    Log(_result);
    initialPrice = parseInt(_result, 2); 

}

 function __callback2(bytes32 _myid, string _result) {
   require (msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
   Log(_result);
   finalPrice = parseInt(_result, 2);
}


function update() payable {
    Log("Oraclize query was sent, waiting for the answer..");
    oraclize_query("URL","json(https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price? 
fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD).USD");
}


function update2() payable {
Log("Oraclize query was sent, waiting for the answer..");
oraclize_query(60 , "URL","json(https://min- 
api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD).USD");
}
```

at the moment in remix I can call the function update and update2 and it will display the eth price etc , but what I want to do is make a function that when called , automatically calls the update and update2 function , im not sure how to do it ? there might be an easy answer , im just a beginner

Comment: What is `function test()`?

Comment: test is the same name as the contract . if I make a new function I can either call the function update or update2 but when I try to call both at the same time it doesnt work , and im not understanding

Comment: @timjest1234 Can you clarify what "it doesn't work" means? How does it fails? Oraclize always use the same function `__callback`, renaming it does nothing. To disambiguate between calls you have to store the id returned by `oraclize_query`. Also you need enough balance to pay for both queries.

Comment: it will call either the update function or update2 function but not both at the same time which is what im trying to do